# Ensuring Scope for Functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I wrote some code that is running and my next battle is re-factoring and I think I'm doing something incorrectly when it comes to scope. I am retrieving message data and I'm trying to modify it:

```
function handleMessage(message) {
if(message.includes('dns')) {
    // Take the data I want and re-organize for the API to use
    // This removes the user ID text <@XXXXXXXXX>
    var buf1 = Buffer.allocUnsafe(26);
    buf1 = message;
    buf2 = buf1.slice(13, buf1.length);
    message = buf2.toString('ascii', 0, buf2.length);

    /* There may be a better way with the Slack API, but this will work
    returns URL as a string without extra formatting. Pre-formatted text appears like:
    <http://webbhost.net|webbhost.net> */
    var n = message.indexOf('|');
    var o = message.indexOf('>');
    var n = n+1;
    var o = o-2;
    var s1 = message.substr(n, o);
    var p = s1.indexOf('>');
    var s2 = s1.substr(0, p);
    message = s2;
    dnsLookup(message);

} else if(message.includes(' whois')) {
    // Take the data I want and re-organize for the API to use
    // This should probably be it's own function
    var buf1 = Buffer.allocUnsafe(26);
    buf1 = message;
    buf2 = buf1.slice(13, buf1.length);
    message = buf2.toString('ascii', 0, buf2.length);

    var n = message.indexOf('|');
    var o = message.indexOf('>');
    var n = n+1;
    var o = o-2;
    var s1 = message.substr(n, o);
    var p = s1.indexOf('>');
    var s2 = s1.substr(0, p);
    message = s2;
    whoisLookup(message);
}
```

Obviously I repeat a lot of code here and I would like to make 2 functions out out of this. Now I tried doing that within this function and it looks like when I do have them set up as functions that I'm not permanently updating the variable I'm sending (when I check the result of the first function and at the beginning of the second, it looks like before the first function was run).

Is there some other way I need to be looking at this? I could do this as one function, but I'm trying to future-proof for other scenarios I may run into in the future.

This is what it looks like after my changes:

```
function handleMessage(message) {
function removeID(message) {
    var buf1 = Buffer.allocUnsafe(26);
    buf1 = message;
    buf2 = buf1.slice(13, buf1.length);
    message = buf2.toString('ascii', 0, buf2.length);

    console.log(message);
    }
function removeSlackURL(message){
    console.log("test");
    console.log(message);
    var n = message.indexOf('|');
    var o = message.indexOf('>');
    var n = n+1;
    var o = o-2;
    var s1 = message.substr(n, o);
    var p = s1.indexOf('>');
    var s2 = s1.substr(0, p);
    message = s2;

}
if(message.includes('dns')) {
    // Take the data I want and re-organize for the API to use
    // This removes the user ID text <@XXXXXXXXX>


    removeID(message);
    removeSlackURL(message);
```

Comment: What is `var n = n+1;` supposed to do? Drop `var`s from the assignments if you already have declared the variable.

Comment: Pedantically, functions are values and don't have a scope. But you mean the scope of the variable that references the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you pass a `message` to a function, you are passing a reference to the string to a separate variable which has scope limited to that function. If you assign a different string to the `message` variable inside the function, it essentially re-assigns that reference to the new value without affecting the original `message` in any way. 
It is equivalent to:

```
var a = 2;
var b = a; //b = 2
b = 3;
console.log(a); //2
```

The `a` here is your original `message` which was passed on to a variable called `message` inside the function which is analogous to `b` here.

The best way to have changes persist would be to return the final modified string from all the functions and use the returned value to replace the initial value.

```
function handleMessage(message){
  function removeID(message){
     ....
     ....
     return buf2.toString('ascii', 0, buf2.length);
  }

  function removeSlackURL(message){
     console.log("test");
     console.log(message);
     var n = message.indexOf('|');
     var o = message.indexOf('>');
     var n = n+1;
     var o = o-2;
     var s1 = message.substr(n, o);
     var p = s1.indexOf('>');
     var s2 = s1.substr(0, p);
     message = s2;
     return message;
  }

  if(message.includes('dns')) {
      // Take the data I want and re-organize for the API to use
      // This removes the user ID text <@XXXXXXXXX>


      message = removeID(message);
      message = removeSlackURL(message);

  ....
  ....
  return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables have functional scope in javascript. The message is already a function variable for outer function, the function inside the outer functions need not have the message variable in it.

The inner function have access to the outer function's variable.

```
function handleMessage(message) {
  function removeID() {
    var buf1 = Buffer.allocUnsafe(26);
    buf1 = message;
    buf2 = buf1.slice(13, buf1.length);
    message = buf2.toString('ascii', 0, buf2.length);

    console.log(message);
  }
  function removeSlackURL(){
    console.log("test");
    console.log(message);
    var n = message.indexOf('|');
    var o = message.indexOf('>');
    var n = n+1;
    var o = o-2;
    var s1 = message.substr(n, o);
    var p = s1.indexOf('>');
    var s2 = s1.substr(0, p);
    message = s2;

  }
  // doing this on either cases
  removeID();
  removeSlackURL();
  if(message.includes('dns')) {
    // Take the data I want and re-organize for the API to use
    // This removes the user ID text <@XXXXXXXXX>
  } else if (message.includes()) {

  }
}
```